# C Memory Management

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

The following is a sketch of how I might have some form of automated memory management in C++:

```
template<class T>
class Ptr{
public:
  /* Some memory management stuff (ref counting etc.)
     as Ptr object is initialized */
  Ptr( ... ) { .. }

  /* Manage reference counts etc. 
     as Ptr object is copied -- might be necessary
     when Ptr is passed to or returned from functions */
  Ptr<T>& operator=( .. ) { .. };

   /* Do memory management stuff
      when this "Pointer" object is destroyed. */
  ~Ptr() { .. }

private:
  /* Pointer to main object */
  T* object;
}

class Obj{
public:
  static Ptr<Obj> newObj( .. ) { return Ptr<Obj>( new Obj( .. ) ); }
private:
  /* Hide constructor so it can only be created by newObj */
  Obj( .. ) { .. }
  /* some variables for memory management routines */
  int refcnt;
  ..
}
```

This way, the end-user never has to call new or malloc, and can instead call Obj.newObj( .. ).

However, I'm pretty stumped on how I might do something similar for C.

It doesn't have to be exactly like above, but I don't want to have to care about memory management when it isn't important.

The biggest issue I feel I have is that when a variable in C goes out of scope, I don't really have a 'destructor' that can be signaled to let me know that the variable has gone out of scope.

Comment: Why are you creating your own smart pointers?

Comment: If you want smart pointers you shouldn't be using C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complete solution and answer to your question see [GObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject).

Comment: Can you please explain how GObject solves the problem of manual memory management? The wikipedia page you linked to doesn't make it clear.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly do you mean by "manual" management?

Comment: I mean what is described in the question: "It doesn't have to be exactly like above, but *I don't want to have to care about memory management* when it isn't important." (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the primary benefit of C++. You can create classes, which encapsulate functionality. And this functionality can include constructors and destructors to ensure that data is created, managed, and destroyed in a controlled manner.

There is no such option in C unless you implement an entire framework that supports such an option.